# How to generate a config file using a list

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed

I have a file (let's call it `input.txt`), which contains

```
hostname.domain.com  111.222.333.444 
hostname2.domain.com 555.666.777.888
...
```

and is about 900 lines long.

Then I have a stanza for a config file, which is

```
<Host "hostname.domain.com">
    Address "111.222.333.444"
    Version 1
    Community "more_communities"
    Collect "powerplus"
    Interval 300
</Host>
```

How can I parse the `input.txt` file so that its hostname and IP go into the proper field and the rest of the stanza is put into a text file?

Comment: Probably you want to parse this in a better way, say xml format. `<Host name = "hostname.domain.com">     
<address>"111.222.333.444"</address>    
<version>1</version>    
<community>"more_communities"</community>    
<interval>300</interval>    
</Host>`

Comment: Apache configuration files aren't precisely XML.

Comment: This is xml-ish format, but it's just a configuration file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [here document](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document):

```
#!/bin/bash

while read -r host number; do
cat << EOF >> output.txt
<Host "$host">
  Address "$number"
  Version 1
  Community "more_communities"
  Collect "powerplus"
  Interval 300
</Host>
EOF
done < input.txt
```

Comment: This will fork/exec `cat` for each line in the input file, which is not an insignificant time cost if there are many lines.

Comment: @Cyrus,  this did it.  I was overthinking it and trying to use awk.

Answer (score 2):

If you described the situation completely, you don't need anything more complicated than a simple shell script:

```
#!/bin/sh
while read -r host ip _; do
    printf '<Host "%s">\n' "$host"
    printf '    Address "%s"\n' "$ip"
    echo   '    Version 1'
    echo   '    Community "more_communities"'
    echo   '    Collect "powerplus"'
    echo   '    Interval 300'
    echo   '</Host>'
done < input.txt > output.txt
```

Note that I'm assuming this is an Apache httpd configuration file, not XML.

Comment: This gets me "./input.txt: line 553: hostname.domain.com: command not found"  for each line in the input.txt

Comment: @nutriux how are you running it? It looks as if you've somehow embedded the script into the input file.

Comment: I ran it as is.   Not sure why it was acting the way it was.